# How to use :active or :focus styles in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have an image gallery where I want to select image and style selected one with green border. :hover works fine but :focus and :active are not applying to my img element. As soon as move mouse from the image my green borde goes away, but I want it to stay on selected image

[image]

Styles:

```
 image: {

    '&:hover': {
        border: '1px solid green'
   },
   '&:active': {
        border: '1px solid green'
   },
   '&:focus': {
        border: '1px solid green'
   },
```

Image that comes from map(Array...)

```
 <img
      className={classes.image}
      alt='My image'
      src={img}
      onDoubleClick={() => this.openImage}
 />
```

Comment: `active` and `focus` will work after clicking on that element unlike `hover`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your `img` element to be able to receive focus by adding the `tabindex` (`tabIndex` in React) property. A `tabindex` of -1 lets you focus an element using the mouse, though not using the <kbd>tab</kbd> key.

```
<img
  className={classes.image}
  alt='My image'
  src={img}
  onDoubleClick={() => this.openImage}
  tabIndex={-1}
/>
```